# Is there a list of minimum gcc version supporting each __attribute__?

Tags: c, gcc, attributes

The official documentation here only lists the minimum required version for a very small number of attributes:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Is there a complete list of which version each attribute was added in? Even better would be a list that also shows which ones are compatible with pcc and tcc.

Comment: pcc? I suppose that's not the Presbyterian Church of Canada...

Comment: Why do you care?  Are you targeting really old versions of GCC?

Comment: @Adam Perhaps the OP knows how to write portable code and wishes to protect uses of these attributes with appropriate version guards.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: Does it matter?

Comment: pcc is http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For gcc versions:

http://www.ohse.de/uwe/articles/gcc-attributes.html

For pcc:

http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se/fisheye/browse/~raw,r=HEAD/pcc/pcc/cc/ccom/gcc_compat.c

For tcc:

??

Answer (score 2):

For a lot of the useful ones you can copy the gcc version tests from glib's gmacros.h:
http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/gmacros.h

Depending on your project you may also be able to just use GLib, and then use G_GNUC_NORETURN or whatever instead of the `__attribute__` directly.

It probably would be better in principle to do HAVE_GCC_ATTRIBUTE_NORETURN as Juliano suggests, but it may also be YAGNI work, depending on your project.

Answer (score 1):

I found this link which is slightly newer than the accepted answer:
https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/gcc/patch/20170706132518.GO3988@redhat.com/

Apparently up to 8.1.0. Not sure it is complete though.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and don't do that.

Perhaps your software has some pre-compilation configuration/setup phase (like the autoconf team... ugh! (*shivers*) or something more sane like CMake), use that.

Write small tests (autoconf macros) that check if the compiler accepts the `__attribute__` you are interested in and if it works as expected. If successful, write a `HAVE_GCC_ATTRIBUTE_XXX` macro in a `config.h` file which is included from your source.

Then use that macro with `#ifdef` to test if you should put or not the attribute in the function, or perhaps if you should use another hack to emulate the lack of the attribute.

Comment: I disagree with this answer for several reasons. Whether you hard-code versions or test for support, you need to **know** as a developer what you're depending on to decide how to handle compilers that don't support it. For an attribute that every known compiler supports (e.g. `const`), it would be reasonable to elect not to implement any fallback if it fails to exist, and simply let the compiler generate redundant function calls if the attribute is not available...

Comment: ...while other attributes that are only supported in recent gcc versions, or only in gcc but not other compilers, might require more elaborate fallbacks, or (more likely) just shouldn't be used at all unless they result in a major practical benefit that's impossible to achieve in another way.

Comment: You're both right, depending on *why* you want to know - if you're deciding which attributes to use in your code, then knowing which versions support them is relevant to your decision-making.  But at build-time, checking directly for support rather than checking the compiler version is better, since that will allow you to support other compilers that you hadn't considered that may implement the attribute (icc? clang?).

Comment: By the way, one attribute I was dealing with which could be dangerous like this is `regparm`. I'm dealing with a (poorly designed) defined library ABI where a public function is declared `regparm` (pass-by-register on i386), but I want my code and interface headers to be portable to non-gcc compilers. I think my solution is just going to be including inline asm for i386 to make the function calls... :-(